# Implement OS-based stylesheets in XUL

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I'm a friend clean GUI's. Unfortunately I need to overwrite the "chrome://global/skin" stylesheets for some reason.

What's the best method, **to implement different os-based stylesheets into xul-documents** - eg. for GUI's like windows xp, windows aero or macosx aqua (overlay-aero.css, overlay-aqua.css...).

Does Mozilla provide any standards for os-based stylesheet-implementing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without really knowing how you intend to overlay the styles: yes, the usual approach would be using [manifest flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_flags). For example, if you define a [style overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#style) in your extension's `chrome.manifest` file, you would do it like this:

```
style chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myExtension/skin/overlay-win.css os=WINNT
style chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myExtension/skin/overlay-osx.css os=Darwin
style chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myExtension/skin/overlay-linux.css os=Linux
```

You can also use [Mozilla-specific media features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/media_queries#Mozilla-specific_media_features) to distinguish between different themes of one OS in your stylesheet. For example:

```
@media all and (-moz-windows-classic)
{
  ...
}
@media all and (-moz-windows-theme: aero)
{
  ...
}
@media all and (-moz-windows-compositor)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to create your own Firefox Theme (essential an extension made up of CSS files and images that replace the standard look of the browser). There's a whole section about this on Mozilla Development Center: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/how-to/theme-development

Comment: thank you, Matthew. You're wrong, I do not want to create "another theme". It's for a complex extension. For example: I display two groupboxes in aero in a simple row `(display: table-cell;)` - but this solution looks stupid in macosx. How can I implement a aero.css-file only for aero users?